# HKObserverQuery completionHandler

Tags: ios, healthkit

I'm trying to make an app that uses HealthKit weight data and sends it to a remote server. Should I put the completionHandler in the "success" hook of the async request to the server or should completionHandler always be called if error is nil (this seems to be how most examples are written).

Comment: It's not clear to me what part of using an HKObserverQuery you have a question about. Could you provide code snippets demonstrating the question?

Answer (score 0):

The completionHandler should always be called. If you don't call it, including in the case of errors, then Apple will eventually stop calling your query in the background. Be advised, HealthKit data is encrypted when the device's screen is of and if it has a pass-code set. While it is encrypted the data is unreadable, even though the HKObserverQuery will still notify you that something has changed (you just can't tell what was changed). The encryption makes background processing of HealthKit data almost impossible unless the user disables their passcode/touchid (which obviously is not advisable).